# Django show unique together fields in one model in another model's template

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

A Django newbie here. I have searched but couldn't find an answer to my question (or I didn't know the right keywords to look up)
I have a model with a unique together columns in addition to a PK-

```
class RegEntry(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
product = models.ForeignKey('data.Product', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
account_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)
nominee_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
nominee_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
nominee_account_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True

objects = RegisterQuerySet.as_manager()

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('date', 'product', 'nominee_id'),)
    index_together = (
        ('nominee_id', 'date'),
        ('product', 'date'),
    )
    ordering = ['date', 'product', 'nominee_id']
```

I have another model that is based on the previous model and has it's own PK -

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
product = models.ForeignKey('data.Product', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
nominee_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
beneficiary_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('date', 'product', 'nominee_id', 'beneficiary_name'),)
    index_together = (
        ('date', 'product', 'nominee_id'),
        ('is_processed',)
    )
    ordering = ['date', 'product', 'nominee_id', 'beneficiary_name']
```

I need to display the Attribute model using ModelForm and associated template, but also need to display the product name and nominee name. I got to the part where I could render Model Form but couldn't figure out the linking part. Will be very grateful for any advice from the experts here.

Comment: You don't need to define primary key field https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: What is exactly the problem when you render your form? What is the "linking part"?

Comment: @guillermochamorro - I need to display Attribute details but also show corresponding RegEntry records. The link between these two models are the 'date', 'product', 'nominee_id' fields.
For each Attribute record, how do I retrieve RegEntry records? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself, if I use the .extra() method and SQL where clause, I can get the results I want.
This blog and example on using extra is what I ended up following -
https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-filter-a-django-queryset-using-extra/

I haven't tested this solution for performance yet, currently our dataset is small and I have checked to understand this particular table will only have a handful of records at any given point in time.